# Get Substring from a String from __

Tags: java, string

I want to extract subString from a String, starting from `__`(Double UnderScore) till a `"`(Double Quotes) or special character `'[](),'` is found.

I have been at it for some while now but cannot figure it out.

For Example: Input String : `"NAME":"__NAME"`

Required String : `__NAME`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1. find the position of `__` 2. substring from that position. 3. in the new string: find the position of `"`. 4. substring until that position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex `(__(.*?))[\"\[\]\(\),]` to get what you want you can use :

```
String str = "\"NAME\":\"__NAME\"";
String regex = "(__(.*?))[\"\\[\\]\\(\\),]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
__NAME
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SgT1iG/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try following code

```
String input="\"NAME\":\"__NAME\"";
int startIndex=input.indexOf("__");
int lastIndex=input.length();
String output=input.substring(startIndex, (lastIndex-1));
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: i think the algorith from @ParkerHalo describes a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

May this solution help you:

```
import java.util.*;
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String a=s.next();
        int i=a.indexOf("__");
        int j=a.indexOf('"',i);
        System.out.println(a.substring(i,j));
       }
}
```

In this firstly we calculate the index of `__` and then we calculate the index of `"` after `__`.and then use `substring` method to get desired output.